# Intercepting Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want my application to intercept the Intent.CATEGORY_HOME intent, ONLY *only if my main Activity is running*. From what I've read, you intercept intents with a Broadcast Receiver declared in your manifest. So in this case, I only want the broadcast receiver to take action if my main Activity is running.

Is this the correct approach?
Can I communicate between my broadcast receiver and my main activity?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: you dont have to have broadcast receivers in your manifest, you can also declare them in your code..just an FYI

Comment: that's probably closer to what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

> I want my application to intercept the Intent.CATEGORY_HOME intent, ONLY only if my main Activity is running

That is not possible. Either your application is the home screen, or it is not the home screen.

> From what I've read, you intercept intents with a Broadcast Receiver declared in your manifest.

No. You can receive broadcast `Intent`s with a `BroadcastReceiver`. Starting an activity -- such as bringing the home screen to the foreground -- is not a broadcast.